# JSF java.lang.ClassNotFoundException org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceName when filtering PrimeFaces Datatable

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

I can't seem to track down this error.

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceName from [Module "deployment.OpsSkills.war:main" from Service Module Loader]

It a Maven based JSF application created using Eclipse.  The application runs fine on my machine, but not deployed to the DEV server.  The exception is thrown when I try to use the FilterBy parameter on a PrimeFaces datatable, or use the pagination buttons.  The table displays fine in DEV, but when I type a character into the filter box in the column header, the exception is thrown.

What is really annoying is that I have other similar apps running on this DEV server where the Primefaces Datatable filters fine.  So I tried copying a working eclipse project to a new folder, blowing away just that source code putting in the source code for the troubled app.  I tried this because when I initially created the new app I used maven to generate boilerplate and unfortunately it was using newer versions for things like webmodule, jsf, jpa, etc.. Our DEV servers are running (and no I can't upgrade to WildFly):

```
Server info: JBoss Web/7.0.13.Final
Servlet version: 3.0
Java version: 1.6.0_40
```

So I wanted to use existing, known to work web.xml, beans.xml, faces-config, etc...Still the exception is thrown.
   I then put the `FilterView` demo files from PF Showcase and THEY WORK IN DEV.  The difference is it is not using db backing tables, whereas mine are.  Also different for this new app to one of my apps where PF DT works, is that the new apps db tables are on a different Oracle datasource, if that matters (the defunct app deploys and the initial datatable displays data so I don't see a correlation).

Here is some relevant code:

```
 <h:form>
 <p:dataTable id="certTable" var="cert" value="#{certificationView.list}" emptyMessage="No records found" paginator="true" paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}" rowsPerPageTemplate="25,50,100" rows="50" filteredValue="#{certification.filteredList}">

      <p:column headerText="Title" sortBy="#{cert.certTitle}" filterBy="#{cert.certTitle}" filterMatchMode="contains"
       <h:outputText value="#{cert.certTitle}" />
      </p:column>
```

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class CertificationView implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Inject
private CertificationRepository dao;

private List<Certification> list;
private List<Certification> filteredList;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    list = dao.retrieveAll();
}
```

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class CertificationEBRepository extends DataAccessService<CertificationEB, String> {

@Inject
@MyDatabase
private EntityManager em;

public List<Certification> retrieveAll() {
    Query query = em.createQuery("My Query");
    List<Certification> result = query.getResultList();
    return result;
}
```

**How to solve this error?**

Answer (score 0):

OK so in my web.xml I had

```
    <context-param>
   <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
   <param-value>client</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

Not sure why this is crashing PF datatable?

But once I removed it, PF datatable filters and the pagination works.